# Some image links broken when pushed to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have placed some default fallback images in the usual place: `app/assets/images`.

I refer to them using the Refile fallback option:

`<%= attachment_image_tag(current_user.avatars.first, :file, :fill, 18, 18, class: 'img-responsive, img-circle', fallback: asset_path('avatar_18') %>`.

I have also tried `fallback: 'avatar_18'` and `fallback: ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('avatar_18'))`.

But the image links on Heroku are broken. I can see that the assets are being precompiled, and the other image files work just fine.

I inspected the element, and the path looks to be wrong: `<img class="attachment  file img-responsive, img-circle fallback" src="/avatar_18" alt="Avatar 18">`.

But presumably, the path should be something like the following (which works): `<img src="/assets/stripe-connect-b97267f03e002d67bf29c5efef5c5364c771a0c3bde885284ecafc5356ce2ea4.png" alt="Stripe connect b97267f03e002d67bf29c5efef5c5364c771a0c3bde885284ecafc5356ce2ea4">`.

How can I get the correct path?

EDIT:

- `fallback: image_tag('avatar_18')` does not produce any image in development.
- `fallback: image_path('avatar_18')` works in development, but not in production; the source is wrong: `src="/images/avatar_18"`. That should be `assets`, not `images`.
- `fallback: asset_path('avatar_18')` works in development, but not in production; the source is wrong: `src="/avatar_18"`. The path is missing `assets`. Also, the digest is missing.
- `ls public/assets` shows the file `avatar_18-3c7e2d23b8adbdf979eff7152c156b18817f26b4ceae7525dcdded75d523a052.png`.
- I have also tried checking the asset_path: `irb(main):001:0> puts helper.asset_path('avatar_18.png')
  /assets/avatar_18-3c7e2d23b8adbdf979eff7152c156b18817f26b4ceae7525dcdded75d523a052.png
  => nil`

Not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add the file extension. No helpers needed.

Example:

```
<%= attachment_image_tag(current_user.avatars.first, :file, :fill, 18, 18, class: 'img-responsive, img-circle', fallback: 'avatar_18.png' %>.
```